# How to increase resolution of numpy pipeline density plots?

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, mayavi

```
figure = mlab.figure('DensityPlot')

grid = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(xi, yi, zi, density)
min = density.min()
max=density.max()
mlab.pipeline.volume(grid, vmin=min, vmax=max)

mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

My code generates a 3d density plot. However the plot is very choppy. How does one increase the resolution? Am I supposed to increase the number of points, or change the interpolation procedure used by pipeline?